# Hover text-decoration: none; does not work in IE

Tags: css, wordpress, text-decorations

I read through the other similar posts but I still can't get the text-decoration: none to work in IE. It works in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox.  The pages are also on WordPress (if it makes any difference).

CSS I'm using:

```
.glyphNext:after {
display: inline-block;
font-family: CaGov; 
content: "\e669";
padding-left: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-decoration: none!important;
}
.glyphNext:hover::after {
text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

Any other ideas? I only want the text link to be underlined, I don't want my glyph to be underlined on hover.

Comment: Post the HTML, too.

Answer (score 0):

First, what is `.glyphNext`? Is it an anchor tag?

If it is an anchor tag, attach the `text-decoration: none;` to the selector like so:

```
.glyphNext, .glyphNext:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```